# Would mathematics based on lists obviate the need for the axiom of choice?

Tags: axiom-of-choice, foundations, alternative-set-theories

I'm trying to wrap my head around the axiom of choice and its equivalent well-ordering theorem. Imagine a mathematics founded on ordered lists rather than sets. So by construction, wouldn't every mathematical object would be well-ordered and thus wouldn't the axiom of choice merely be a theorem rather than an axiom? Would this "list theoretic" mathematics be less expressive than ZFC?

Answer (score 4):

Well, the question is what is a list. If a list is just a well ordered set, then in principle you are correct.

In some sense this is similar to working with Global Choice, where every set has a distinguished well ordering.

The problem is formalizing lists is somehow more elaborate than formalizing sets. Since lists have an inherent structure to them, you need to incorporate this into your language and into your semantics. It's not impossible, but what do you get that you can't do with ZFC, or ZF+Global Choice? Ultimately, not much.

Comment: Isn't there a sense, though, in which lists are actually *less* complicated than sets? Lists are elements of noncommutative monoids, whereas sets are elements of commutative idempotent monoids, which have strictly *more* structure. Simpler and more general still would be ordered trees composed of pairs.

Comment: And what is a monoid? Also what exactly do you mean by a list? What is a list of length $\omega_1+\omega^{53}+321$? And if transfinite length don't make sense, how do you expect to have a foundation of mathematics?

Comment: Hmm. That's a good point. I guess in order to define a list we'd need a more elaborate foundational system than set theory, for example, a type theory. In type theory it is easy to create a list type but more difficult to create the set type. But in order to do conventional mathematics we still bother constructing the set type and using them, however, I wonder if we could do analogous conventional mathematics just using lists and by doing so not even need the axiom of choice.

Comment: @Brandon: Sets are still more natural. Say that you have a proof that a certain thing has only finitely many objects (e.g. finitely many roots of a polynomial over an arbitrary field), and that these are well-defined. Then using a list means that your result depends on the order in which you list them, so your proof is now more complicated because you need to utilise "up to a permutation of the list", or some other auxiliary lemma to guarantee that the result does not matter on the order of listing.

Comment: There is an axiomatisation of such a theory of hereditary lists: DEISER, O. (2011). AN AXIOMATIC THEORY OF WELL-ORDERINGS. The Review of Symbolic Logic, 4(2), 186-204. doi:10.1017/S1755020310000390.  Here’s a quote (pp. 201-202): _(2) The axiom of choice is a genuinely set theoretical principle which does not need any analogon in list theory in the presence of a hierarchy, since then the principle (CC) of collective choice is easily provable_.  But there is another axiom (called SL), corresponding to the powerset axiom, which seems to be where the bump under the carpet got moved to.

Comment: @VejKse: Yes, if you build well-orders into every object, you can prove the axiom of choice, why is this surprising to anyone?. Alternatively, you can follow Hilbert's $\varepsilon$ operator and just build the axiom of choice into your logic, lo and behold, we have obviated ourselves from the need to discussion AC as a set theoretic axiom!

Answer (score 1):

The usual proof that well-ordering implies a choice function $f$ exists on $X\not\owns\emptyset$ notes that if $\le$ well-orders $\bigcup X$, any $x\in X$ has a $\le$-minimal element, say $y$, because $x\subseteq\bigcup X$; we can thus define $f(x):=y$.

This argument requires $\bigcup X$ to exist for each such $X$. In set theory, that's no problem; it's the [axiom of union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_union). For a theory of sorted lists to work the same way, we need the union to admit a specific ordering as well.

So if your universe of objects is well-ordered, every list can just be an ordered sample therein, in which case choice is trivial. But then you're basically studying, in a non-standard formalism, the subsets of some universe nowhere near as general as we like to consider in foundational mathematics.

For example, our ordered lists could be of ordinals, so $<=\in$. It's true we can construct an easy choice function on any set of nonempty sets of ordinals. But one cannot, for example, easily identify the real numbers (or which are less naturally ordered, the complex ones) with ordinals in a way that makes this useful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe working in the [constructible universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe), or Gödel's model of ZF would be interesting for you. There we restrict our universe (to so-called constructible sets), so that Choice becomes a theorem and we also have a "constructive" well-order of the whole universe. It solves many independent questions in a definite way (GCH holds e.g., and there is a Suslin line and many more interesting objects).